# What was the weight of the Aron?

Tags: beis-hamikdash

The exact weight of the ark is impossible to determine since there are different views on the measurements and the thickness of the materials in the Mishkan. I am interested in finding sources or Seforim that address this question according to various opinions. Please cite sources.

Comment: הארון נשא את נושאיו. So maybe it didn't have a weight? Like it didn't really have dimensions either (מקום הארון אינו מן המידה)

Comment: thank you Issac for finding this question, I did try to search for it...